# Add custom item on SelectListItem in If condition in a controller ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, selectlistitem

Trying to populate a DropDownList depending on logged in windows user's username. However, the list should have only one item if the condition fails.

**Problem:** The custom item is not added to the list when condition meets. Looked at lot of posts on SO but with no luck. Any direction would help.

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Location()
    {
        UserPermissionDataContext dbContext = new UserPermissionDataContext();
        var viewModel = new UserDetail();
        var locationList = new SelectList(
                            (
                                from t in dbContext.UserDetails
                                where t.username.Equals(System.Environment.UserName)
                                select new SelectListItem{Text = t.location, Value = t.level}
                            ), "Value", "Text");

        if (locationList.Select(i => i.Value).Contains("Global"))
            ViewData["Locations"] = locationList;
        else
            ViewData["Locations"] = new SelectList(locationList, "Value", "No Access");
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**View:**

```
<tr>
    <td>Global</td>
    <td>
        <div> 
            @Html.DropDownList("location", (SelectList)ViewData["Locations"])
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What would be the steps to generate a list in that case when condition failes with one item only which would have the item as "No Access".

Comment: What is the point of a `<select>` with only one item (there is nothing to _select_)? And the code in the `else` block would throw an exception because `SelectListItem` does not contain a (invalid) property named `No Access`

Comment: Have you stepped through the action to see that `ViewData["Locations"]` is set as you expect? Have you set a breakpoint on that line in the view to see what the value of `ViewData["Locations"]` is? You seem to be implying that what it's set to in the action and what you get from it in the view are not the same.  Is that the case?  If not then the issue would appear to be solely in the action and that your `locationList` contains the value "Global" when you don't think it should.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are right, but not aware of a better option.Because I need the list if there is data with "Global".But if not then nothing else shoudl be displayed but a custom text which doesn't exist in DB. "No access" is just the TEXT that should be added and that is what don't know how to add.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes.But in DB there is no "Global" data hence the list should ignore the rest of the data.

Comment: @sharlene, Then in your `if` block just add something like `ViewBag.CanAcess = true;` (and delete the `else` block) and then in the view, `if (ViewBag.CanAcess) { // generate the dropdownlist } else { <div>No Access</div> }`

Comment: The fact that you think that something SHOULD happen isn't all that relevant.  The code isn't doing what it's supposed to so something that you think SHOULD be happening is not.  Throw out your assumptions and actually use you eyes.  LOOK at the code as it executes and LOOK at the data being used and check whether it IS what you think it SHOULD be.

Comment: And what do you expect your `where t.username.Equals(System.Environment.UserName)` to return you publish your app? - it will return the name of the server

Comment: @StephenMuecke: It is expected to return the logged in user's username and it does.

Comment: It wont when you publish it (its only doing that because your running it on your machine)

Comment: @StephenMuecke will change so that it returns logged in window's user's username. Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 if (locationList.Any(i => i.Value.Contains("Global")))
```